# How can a Chrome extension communicate with a system process?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The [1Password chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/1password-password-manage/aomjjhallfgjeglblehebfpbcfeobpgk) reads and writes to the same data store as the main system (in my case, OS X) app. How can it do this?

Comment: @JeremyBanks Not in this case, interestingly enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifically in the case of 1Password, it uses [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to connect to a local (127.0.0.1) server which the desktop component of 1Password presumably runs.

Alternatively, an extension can launch a system process with [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).